# ValueError: Lengths must match to compare

Tags: python, analysis

I have a data set with zip codes that I need to match/compare with `"Cong Zip Codes"`. There are not as many Cong zip codes as Zip codes so I have filled in the rest of the values with zeroes. I have already found out the zip codes that overlap and I have saved them to a variable called `intersecting_zipps`. I am trying to use np.select to print a new True/False column if zip codes overlap. I am using `np.select`:

```py
conditions = [ intersecting_zipps == df['Zip Code'], intersecting_zipps != df['Zip Code'] ]
values = [T, F]
df['new'] = np.select(conditions, values)
```

However, since the zeroes in the Cong zip column don't match the length of my Zip code column, I get a Value error. How do I go about this?

Data-set:

[image: date set]

Answer (score 0):

One way is to convert the zip codes to strings and add leading zeros to "Cong Zip Codes":

```
df['Zip Code'] = df['Zip Code'].astype(str)
df['Cong Zip Codes'] = df['Cong Zip Codes'].astype(str).map(lambda x: x.zfill(5))
```